# How to output only the match string using Python?

Tags: python, string, list, output, match

I want to match a string then print the string that matched.

I need to match a string `mapping=C111` from all those lists.
Here what I tried. I can find the matched string but I can not print only the matched string.

```
import re
AllString = ["123A","B456","AGHF\C111\B321","3FEW/D654"]
print(type(AllString))
for str in AllString:
    mapping = "C111"
    findid = [re.match(mapping, str)]
    for f in findid:
       if f is not None:
           print(f)
```

The output is like this:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='C111'>
```

My expectation result is `"AGHF\C111\B321"` the whole string.

Anyone can help, please. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
AllString = ["123A","B456","C111\B321","3FEW/D654"]
print(type(AllString))
for str in AllString:
    mapping = "C111"
    findid = [re.match(mapping, str)]
    for f in findid:
       if f is not None:
           print(f.string) # output: C111\B321 and It makes sense
```

OR:

```
import re
AllString = ["123A","B456","C111\B321","3FEW/D654"]
print(type(AllString))
for str in AllString:
    mapping = "C111"
    findid = [re.match(mapping, str)]
    for f in findid:
       if f is not None:
           print(mapping) # It meets your requirement but looks weird
```

NEW UPDATED:

```
import re
AllString = ["123A","B456","AGHF\C111\B321","3FEW/D654"]
print(type(AllString))
for str in AllString:
    mapping = r".+C111.+" # method 'match' should be used with regex
    findid = [re.match(mapping, str)]
    for f in findid:
       if f is not None:
           print(f.string)
```

Comment: hi @Gcode. I tried your first answer, it only works when I have `"C111\B321"` but my update case it "AGHF\C111\B321", and it does not work. It does not work if the target string in the middle like `"AGHF\C111\B321"`. Could you please help me. Thank you

Comment: I changed it to  `findid = [re.search(mapping, str)]` it works. Thank you. You can edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the code is `re.match` must match at the start of the string.  You could use `re.search` instead, but there is no need for a regular expression in this case.  Use `in`:

```py
strings = ['123A','B456','AGHF\C111\B321','3FEW/D654']
for s in strings:
    if 'C111' in s:
        print(s)
```

```
AGHF\C111\B321
```

If you need to match the *exact* alphanumeric sequence with no extra letters/numbers around it then use `re.search` with `\b` (word breaks):

```py
import re

strings = ["123A","B456","C111\B321","3FEW/ABC111DEF/D654","ABC\C111/DEF"]

for s in strings:
    if re.search(r'\bC111\b',s):
        print(s)
```

```
C111\B321
ABC\C111/DEF
```